# Compiling ffmpeg with an output device (decklink)

Tags: ffmpeg

I've gone through the ffmpeg compile tutorial and have managed to get it working as expected. The build looks stable and usable. However now I need to include the Blackmagick Decklink SDK in the build using the --enable-decklink flag.

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
cd ffmpeg && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-decklink \
  --enable-nonfree && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install && \
hash -r
```

However after a few seconds it fails and reports that it cannot find the decklink libs:

```
ERROR: DeckLinkAPI.h not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

I've placed the libraries in the same folder specified by extra-cflags and in the ldflags. So basically the Decklink SDK is available here and here:

```
~/ffmpeg_build/include/decklink
~/ffmpeg_build/lib/decklink
```

That's not apparently how you do it though. I'm wondering where I should be putting the SDK source to ensure the compiler can read it.

Comment: Share ffbuild/config.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the compile command entirely wrong. This ended up working well for me:

```
cd FFmpeg && 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:"$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --pkg-config-flags="--static" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include
-I$HOME/Decklink" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib
-L$HOME/Decklink" --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-decklink --enable-librtmp --enable-openssl &&
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make &&
make install &&
hash -r
```

Answer (score 0):

If compiling on windows, this will get Decklink working with FFMPEG..
[video tutorial - media-autobuild_suite](http://www.macpczone.co.uk/content/building-ffmpeg-windows-10-easy-way-all-extra-codecs-even-though-it-does-take-while-0)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30457674)

Comment: This is useful info and relevant, question actually did not specify OS